# AutoComplete Google Maps API - direct JSON call

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm trying to develop a jQuery mobile application which uses the Google Places API. Essentially what I'm doing is adding an input to a jQuery mobile page , then hooking it up to Google Places to autocomplete an address, and potentially grab the co-ordinates of that address.

I had initial success in [modifying the demos available here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete), which utilise Google's own Autocomplete functionality inside their 'Places Library'. However, from a UI perspective, on mobile devices this implementation won't work - you need to essentially tap a relatively small result, and hitting the return button on the phone doesn't select the first result.

Enter:  http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/3/27/Example-of-Autocomplete-in-jQuery-Mobile

Perfect for what I need, only I'm now trying to get the data returned to be via the Google Places API, using the autocomplete API. See sample API call I'm using:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Amoeba&types=establishment&sensor=true&key=myKeyHERE

This doesn't however return any GEO information - just addresses. Is there a different method or call I need to use? With the native [(Places Library) implementation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#adding_autocomplete), I had access to a whole bunch of data, it didn't require an API key, and didn't need to work within bounds. Not sure if re-geoCoding the resultset seems like the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do cross domain json requests in javascript so hitting the /json end point won't work.

What you should do is go back to your original idea and then style the autocomplete suggestions to be more mobile friendly.

```
.pac-container is the class for the suggest area
.pac-item is the class for each item in the suggest area
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that another call is needed after I have performed the above, the 'reference' field comes back in the initial JSON response. I can cache the results as its only the geo location I need. Although your suggestion was definitely being considered as another potential solution, I prefer this extra level of control over the UI behaviour, even if it is at the cost of additional API requests.

Have given you the Kudos anyway for answering with a decent suggestion.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceDetailsRequests

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CmRYAAAAciqGsTRX1mXRvuXSH2ErwW-jCINE1aLiwP64MCWDN5vkXvXoQGPKldMfmdGyqWSpm7BEYCgDm-iv7Kc2PF7QA7brMAwBbAcqMr5i1f4PwTpaovIZjysCEZTry8Ez30wpEhCNCXpynextCld2EBsDkRKsGhSLayuRyFsex6JA6NPh9dyupoTH3g&sensor=true&key=[yourKey]](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CmRYAAAAciqGsTRX1mXRvuXSH2ErwW-jCINE1aLiwP64MCWDN5vkXvXoQGPKldMfmdGyqWSpm7BEYCgDm-iv7Kc2PF7QA7brMAwBbAcqMr5i1f4PwTpaovIZjysCEZTry8Ez30wpEhCNCXpynextCld2EBsDkRKsGhSLayuRyFsex6JA6NPh9dyupoTH3g&sensor=true&key=%5ByourKey%5D)